# Extract only the text from entity-encoded HTML inside an XML element

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I'm working on an XML parsing Android application but I have a problem. The page I'm going to parse has an element `<description>` in which there sometimes appears entity-encoded HTML which is not wanted. This is the structure:

```
<description>&lt;img src="http://images.website.it/thumbs/images/2014/12/16/asd_crop_upscale_q85.jpg" alt="Post img " style="float:left;margin-right:10px"/&gt; Lorem ipsum...</description>
```

What exactly I want is the `Lorem ipsum...` part and none of the encoded HTML inside the tag `<description>`. This is my `doInBackground` part of `AsyncTask`

```
@Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
           Element e = null;
           XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
           String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
           Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
           NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

           // looping through all item nodes <item>
           for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
               // creating new HashMap
               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
               e = (Element) nl.item(i);
               // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
               map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
               map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
               map.put(KEY_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE));
               map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));

               String descriptionElementContent = KEY_DESC;
               textOnly = removeEntityEncodedHtmlTags(descriptionElementContent);

               // adding HashList to ArrayList
               menuItems.add(map);
           }
           System.out.println("prova3");
           for (int c = 0; c < nl.getLength(); c++) {
               e = (Element) nl.item(c);
               titoli[c] = parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE); // name child value
               descrizioni[c] = parser.getValue(e, textOnly);
               date[c] = parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE);
               links[c] = parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK);
           }
           return null;
       }

       public String removeEntityEncodedHtmlTags(String rawString) {
           Matcher tagMatcher = ENTITY_ENCODED_HTML_TAG.matcher(rawString);
           return tagMatcher.replaceAll("").trim();
       }

        @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Void s) {
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems, R.layout.post_list_item, 
                    new String[] 
                             { KEY_TITLE,
                                textOnly,
                                KEY_DATE

                              }, new int[] 
                                      {
                                        R.id.title,
                                        R.id.description, 
                                        R.id.date
                                    });

            System.out.println("prova5");
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            pDialog.dismiss();          
        }
```

It's the first time I've parsed XML so I don't know how this can be done.

This is my `XMLParser` class by the way:

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     *
     * @param url string
     */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     *
     * @param XML string
     */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

    /**
     * Getting node value
     *
     * @param elem element
     */
    public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
        Node child;
        if (elem != null) {
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null;
                        child = child.getNextSibling()) {
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Getting node value
     *
     * @param Element node
     * @param key string
     */
    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

I editet my quest with new `doInBackground` method. Nothing change

Comment: The XML does not appear to be valid, as it has a tag closure `/>` in the middle of textual content.

Comment: @Arkanon it's correct to me.. this is the link whith all content: http://multiplayer.it/feed/rss/articoli/

Comment: See the descrition part.. i need only the real description

Comment: Looking at the source of the page to which you link, I still believe you have an error in your XML sample. I think it should be `margin-right:10px"/&gt; Lorem ipsum` so that the `>` is encoded to `&gt;`.

Comment: Ok, correct, but anyway I can parse it too..the problem is that there is too much to parse!

Comment: Ok, and, assuming that there is no /> error tag.. Anyway how can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to discard all of the entity-encoded HTML found within the `description` element then you could use a regular expression to find all encoded HTML tags and replace them with an empty string, then trim the resulting string to get rid of unwanted leading and trailing spaces.

You can do this using just the [`String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) but if you're going to do this more than once then it's worth creating a `Pattern` object just once and then using that each time. This avoids the Java runtime having to compile the same regular expression more than once.

I've tested this code and it works against the example XML in your question:

```
private static final Pattern ENTITY_ENCODED_HTML_TAG =
        Pattern.compile("&lt;.*?&gt;");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String descriptionElementContent =
            "&lt;img src=\"http://images.website.it/thumbs/images/2014/12/16/asd_crop_upscale_q85.jpg\" alt=\"Post img \" style=\"float:left;margin-right:10px\"/&gt; Lorem ipsum... &lt;br /&gt;";
    String textOnly = removeEntityEncodedHtmlTags(
            descriptionElementContent);
    System.out.println(textOnly);       
}

public static String removeEntityEncodedHtmlTags(String rawString) {
    Matcher tagMatcher = ENTITY_ENCODED_HTML_TAG.matcher(rawString);
    return tagMatcher.replaceAll("").trim();
}
```

Simply replace the `main` method in the above code with your own loop through the `description` elements.

The regex pattern `&lt;.*?&gt;` says "match the sequence `&lt;` and then any content until the first occurrence of `&gt;`". This pattern is used to instantiate a single static `Pattern` object which can be used (over and over again) to create a `Matcher` object for each raw string you pass to the method. Then the `Matcher.replaceAll` method just replaces every match found (in that raw string) with an empty string to get rid of it from the result, leaving text only.

Comment: Maybe i wrong something but seems not works.. I'm going to edit my question with your code suggestion

Comment: What i want is take only the part `Lorem ipsum... ` or whatever is the content. The patter is the way i'm sure..but maybe i wrong to use it

Comment: In the code in your edited question you are calling the `removeEntityEncodedHtmlTags` and assigning the result to a variable called `textOnly` but you then don't do anything with `textOnly`. Surely you want to store the value of `textOnly` in the map, rather than the raw extracted value?

Comment: Nope, i think I'm wrong..can you please take that my code and try to show me how can I solve?

Comment: the variable textOnly i had declared it as global String variable by the way

Comment: Please when you can help me let me know